# Error creating Job (factory-bean returned null) in Grails quartz plugin

Tags: quartz-scheduler, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I am using Grails 2.2.2 (GGTS - 3.3.0M1) with Quartz plugin 1.0-RC7.

With the following job, I get an error saying that the job instantiation failed when testing with 'grails run-app'. I see the same error if I explicitly call triggerNow() from a controller. The error is as follows:

```
| Error 2013-05-07 10:50:20,260 [quartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] ERROR core.ErrorLogger  - An error occured instantiating job to be executed. job= 'GRAILS_JOBS.mypkg.auth.OAuthJob'
Message: Job instantiation failed
Line | Method
->> 134 | initialize in org.quartz.core.JobRunShell
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
^   387 | run        in org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mypkg.auth.OAuthJob': factory-bean 'mypkg.auth.OAuthJobClass' returned null
```

I created the job with the 'grails create-job' command which added a file under grails-app/jobs/mypkg/auth/OAuthJob.groovy

```
package mypkg.auth

import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException
//import org.grails.plugins.quartz.JobManagerService

class OAuthJob {

def AuthService
def grailsApplication

static triggers = {
    // Execute job once in 11 hours (42600 seconds)
    simple name = "OAuthTokenTrigger", repeatInterval: 426000000l
}

def group = "OAuthJobGroup"

def execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    try {
        log.debug("OAuthJob has been invoked, now requesting token")
        // Call AuthService get token
        AuthService.getToken(context.mergedJobDataMap)
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        throw new JobExecutionException(e.getMessage(), e)
    }
}
}
```

I have added a 'compile ":quartz:1.0-RC7"' dependency to BuildConfig.groovy. 
What am I missing? It doesn't matter if I have the 'group' defined, I get the error nevertheless. I do not see any more errors about why bean creation returns null.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking this not part of the jobs container...

def grailsApplication  <<<- why you referencing this and never using it? :)

another thread/blog or some other craptacular grails documentation methodology had this hint about using one your domain objects to get a handle on the ctx, spring goodness.

```
def grailsApplication = new MyDomain().domainClass.grailsApplication
def ctx = grailsApplication.mainContext
```